# Question about $m^{*}$-measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of intervals of the form $\left ( a,b \right ].$Let  $\alpha(x)=0$ for $x< 0 $ and $1$ for $x\ge 0$.Define $$\mathcal{l}((a,b])=\alpha(b)-\alpha(a);$$ The outer measure $$m^{*}(E)=\inf\{\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}\mathcal{l}(A_i):A_i\in\mathcal{C}\quad\text{for each i and } E\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}\},E\subset \mathbb{R}.$$
A set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is $m^{*}$-measurable  if
$m^{*}(E) = m^{*}(E\cap A)+m^{*}(E\cap A^{c})$,for all $E\subset\mathbb{R}.$

Why the collection of $m^{*}$-measurable sets is the collection of all subsets
of $\mathbb{R}$?
I know the collection of $m^{*}$-measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra contained by the collection of all subsets
of $\mathbb{R}.$

In Bass's Real Analysis Version 4.3 p25 Example 4.4,he said that "the corresponding Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure is point mass at $0$ (defined in Example 3.4), and the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra is the collection of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$"

Comment: You have to use the definition to show that $m^{*}(E)=1$ if $0 \in E$ and $0$ otherwise. And then you have to verify the measurability condition for any set $A$. Unless you  show  some effort on your part it is unlikely that you will get an answer.

Comment: @geetha290krm:Thanks for your hint . I've just verified that $m^{*}(E)=1$ if $0\in E$ and $0$ otherwise.